# Hide TableView Row without removing object array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Ive searched and came up with many different approaches to accomplish hiding a row in a table view. But none seem to work properly and it may be the way i wrote it, not sure. The last example I tried was adjusting its height and when I ran the project all the rows were in one row.

What im trying to accomplish is when landing on this view controller and a bool value is set to false i would like to hide that row BUT not remove it from the array object because when the user presses Send Values button it will send the values for the entire array even though one row may be hidden.

```
#import "SensorValueSystem.h"

@interface SensorValueSystem ()

@end


@implementation SensorValueSystem

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    valueArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
    labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Temp Sensor", @"Humid Sensor", @"UV Sensor", nil];

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 140.0f, 21.0f)];
        [cell addSubview:label];
        [label setTag:456];

        UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
        [cell addSubview:stepper];
        [stepper setTag:123];
        [stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    [cell setTag:indexPath.row];
    int count = [[valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];

    [(UIStepper*)[cell viewWithTag:123] setValue:count];
//    [(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:456] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %d", @"Stepper", count]];
    [(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:456] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:   %d", [labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], count]];


    return cell;
}


- (void)stepperChanged:(UIStepper*)sender {
    int row = [sender.superview tag];
    int value = (int)[sender value];
    NSLog(@"Stepper Name: %@ at Row: %d = %d",[labels objectAtIndex:row], row,value);

    [valueArray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];

    [(UILabel*)[(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview viewWithTag:456] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:   %d", [labels objectAtIndex:row], value]];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)component {
    return [labels count];

}

- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Values of Array: %@", valueArray);
    NSLog(@"Value of Temp: %@", [valueArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"Value of Humid: %@", [valueArray objectAtIndex:1]);
    NSLog(@"Value of UV: %@", [valueArray objectAtIndex:2]);

}

@end
```

Header File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SensorValueSystem : UIViewController{
NSMutableArray *valueArray;
    NSMutableArray *labels;
    int passengers;
    int bags;
    int child;
    bool hideTemp;
    bool hideHumid;
    bool hideUV;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Was able to fix using Josh's answer as well as changing the tags of the steppers in the table view